# Umbraco 7.4 Log member logins into database

Tags: authentication, logging, umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to log when and who has logged in ? (Incl userId and timestamp)

Maybe there's something built into Umbraco 7 or above or do I need to make a custom solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's built inside Umbraco. You can found logs in */App_Data/Logs/...* directory and there you can find the detailed informations about who and when logged in into the panel.

There are also some packages helping to browse and search inside them directly from backoffice e.g. **Diplo Trace Log Viewer** (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/diplo-trace-log-viewer/).

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that you must be logging INFO to be able to see the login info. If you've set your logging to only log errors, you won't be able to see the login info. I think newer versions of Umbraco delete older logs after a while as well, so if you need to keep a longer term record of logins, you may need to archive the files off periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will look into this matter and probably archive the log info in the database to use it for statistics